# Recommendation for a redundant 60V DC Powersupply

Tags: redundancy, power-supply-unit

We have some Telco-Equipment in our data space center which we had been given by our Telco. What they didn't provide is a redundant power supply and therefore we are struggling with outages of this equipment.

What I am searching for is a redundant Power-Supply for 60V and 600W

- 60 Volt DC output
- 600 Watts rated power
- 2 220V Input with galvanic separation
- Rack mountable

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I found out that the Telco Equipment (more precisely a Bosch Marconi FlexPlex) also operates on 48V. I also get a hint from a friendly company that Eltek-Valere produces 48V rectifier in diverse version.

Eventually I will get a 48V 3.2 KW MiniPack from Eltek-Valere to replace the provided PSU from Dt. Telekom.

Link to the product: http://www.eltek-valere.de/en/products/systems/embedded-power/

cheerio
    Lairsdragon

Answer (score 2):

Have you called the telco that loaned (I say loaned because I've never seen a telco just GIVE someone equipment to keep, it's part of your service package) you the equipment and asked them for a more redundant setup?

IMHO that would be the best course of action. If they refuse to give you a redundant setup ... find a new carrier.

Comment: The Powersupply they provided have some redundancy it has two power cords but no galvanic separation, therefore as soon as one phase fails the ground fault circuit interrupter, kills also the second phase. 

The technician from the telco are not very helpful in this case since all they now is that currents comes from the socket in the wall. 

Switching the Telco is not an options since here in germany there are some alternatives but not in rural areas where out company is located.

Comment: Ahh, that sucks. Well, two suggestions (since i still don't think trying to replace thier PSU will go over so well and will probably void just about any SLA that you have with them) 1. Your account manager is probably a better person to talk to abou this, 2) Raise service outage tickets every time it goes down. Keep track of this, then let Accounts Payable know when they've violated their SLA's.

Comment: Well the provided PSU, can be replaced with another PSU without voiding any SLA's since they normally require us to provide 60V and in case the customer has not 60V equipment they provide one for free. Therefore I am searching for a technical solution not for a contractual solution.